# Country balls in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

On 9gag we have something called "country balls". Is it possible to make them in LaTeX TikZ? Are there maybe already a collection of them? Or an easy way to create them?

Maybe there are a usepackage with all flags, and you "just" need to make them round and with some characteristic eyes?

Here are some country balls:

[image]

is it possible to make the last one in tikz? How would you do it?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: [Countryballs must be drawn freehand.](http://polandball.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Polandball_tutorial)

Comment: Don't downvote beyond -1 it is pointless.

Comment: @Werner Any negative number is enough hence -1. Is it a worse question if it has -4 compared to a -7? Or at least that's how I argue.

Comment: @percusse: Not really. I'm of the opinion that a +1/-3 up-/down-vote count (a score of 1-3=-2 then) gives the OP -1 rep (+5-2-2-2=-1). Any fewer down-votes and they actually gain rep.

Comment: @Werner You would be one of the happiest around here if there was really actual credit ;)

Comment: @percusse: I know... I'll be bathing in a gazillion unicoins.

Comment: @percusse I think two of us down-voted (almost) simultaneously. At least. it was at 0. I down-voted, I saw -1 for a second and then it was at -2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know who you are on 9gag, but if you did spend a bit of effort I would be more willing to go all the way but this is where my procrastination brought so far. Now you know how it goes so you can polish it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{germany/.style={circle,draw,fill,minimum size=1cm,
path picture={\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{\foreach \y/\z in {west/w,east/e}{
\coordinate (\z-\x) at 
($(current bounding box.north \y)!\x/3+0.1!(current bounding box.south \y)$);
}}\fill[red] (w-1) to[bend left] (e-1) -- (e-2) to[bend right] (w-2);
\fill[yellow] (w-2) to[bend left] (e-2) -- (e-3) -- (w-3);
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[germany] (a) {};
\draw[ultra thick](-0.35,0.5) -- ++(-15:1);
\fill (-0.35,0.5)++(-15:0.2)--++(75:0.5cm) arc (70:50:2 and 1)--++(250:0.5);
\filldraw[fill=white] (0.15,0.1) --++(0.1,0) arc (-10:-170:0.1 and 0.12)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With apologies to all German friends here :)